# Loading reference dynamically in same namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, system.drawing, system.reflection

I am attempting to customize a proprietary restaurant software called NCR Back Office (formerly Menulink), but am struggling to load System.Drawing even though I can see it is a referenced assembly through the use of System.Reflection.

One of the features is the ability to create a custom workflow which is primarily a series of MessageBox and redirects to various places throughout the application. Creation of these workflows is done via a series of dropdowns. It is also possible to replace this thinly veiled code with custom code entirely (bat, VB, VB.NET). I would like to add a custom form and have created a sample implementation to see if it is possible but I receive the error "Reference required to assembly System.Drawing[...]".

Several other assemblies are included as references include System.Reflection. I was able to determine that System.Drawing was loaded through the use of the following code

```
Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
Dim assems As [Assembly]() = currentDomain.GetAssemblies()
Dim assem As [Assembly]
For Each assem In  assems
    MessageBox.Show(assem.ToString())
Next assem
```

Frustratingly the loaded assembly corresponds exactly to the one referenced in the error (same version, public key, etc).

If am am able to get a handle on the assembly as a System.Reflection.Assembly is there anyway to use methods from that assembly directly to load the assembly into the System.Drawing namespace? Would System.Drawing show up as as in the current domain if it wasn't referenced?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

I see System.Drawing is loaded in the application based on what I was able see loaded up in AppDomain. But I can access it. Can I reload it with the assembly reference into System.Drawing?

Comment: A little confused on what you're asking for. 1: Do you want to load a DLL dynamically (like an addin)? 2: Are you trying to make something in one namespace(ns) show up in another ns? As far as I know you cant. IE, System.Drawing cannot be forces to show up under the System.Reflection NS. Perhaps your question should be about why you are getting the "Reference required to assembly ..". I would guess you need to add the reference through the project references UI.

Comment: @steve Absolutely, I'm confused myself, I'm not a .NET guy so I think my vocabulary is betraying me a little bit. 1) I don't want to, but I'm under the impression I have to since I can access anything in System.Drawing but it appears to be referenced. 2) I know System.Drawing is referenced so I'm trying to find a way to call "reload" it if you will preferably so it inhabits System.Drawing. Unfortunately I'm in a very convoluted environment (code is ran outside of my control and I don't know the environment aside from what I've been able to find) and can't add it like a normal reference.

Comment: @Esoteric Under System.Drawing there are more name spaces [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145023(v=vs.110).aspx) Perhaps you didn't add all references eg. System.Drawing.Design.dll which is not System.Drawing.dll